# how to save group by result to variable or another table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, group-by

I'm not familiar with stored procedure yet. For optimize a time consuming operation of `select count(1)`. I want to save the result to another table or dictionary data structure. 
and I can quickly fetch the value of a given keyword.

Such as:

`select name, count(1) 
from mytable where ... group by name`

How to save pairs of name and count to another table or a dictionary data structure?

Comment: More elegant way would be to use MATERIALIZED VIEW in this case.

Comment: `create table stuff as select ...;`

Comment: @MiroslavDuník thanks. Currently I'm use a table with cusor fetch loop to save result. It's good idea with view if I know how to matintenance it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's also a good idea if it can define PR when create table.

Comment: The operation should not be very time consuming if you devine an appropiate index on the table - so the database can get the data by an index scan and doesn't need access to the table...
Though it depends on the where clause if this is possible.